# Window focus gets "stuck" - cannot click outside of window

Tags: 18.04, xorg

I'm going to preface this by saying that I've seen many, many bug reports and threads with very similar issues, but no useful fixes. Using Ubuntu 18.04 and Xorg.

For some applications, clicking inside the window causes window focus to be "stuck" on that window until the application is closed. I can move the mouse freely, and scrolling works sometimes. I cannot move the "stuck" window or hit the `x` in the corner, but I can click within the window and alt tab to other applications. Alt tabbing to any other application will move that window to the top, but any clicks are registered on the "stuck" application. Sometimes, this brings the "stuck" application back to the front, sometimes not.

Comment: Update: Further testing has revealed other weird stuff with other programs. More importantly, I found a spare mouse and discovered that the issue is with the rat7 mouse I was using before. I suspect there are some proprietary drivers I am missing. More to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed my own issue! Turns out a good night's rest and some breakfast does a lot to help your troubleshooting abilities (what a surprise.) As mentioned in my comment, the problem was with my rat 7 mouse. Followed the third post on [this forum page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1528982&page=3) and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same bug too, for me it usually happens after my pc crashes (for some reason I cant figure out) however, if I get the bug where focus gets stuck to a window what I found out to work (at least as long the computer was on) was to logout and then log back in