# Gnome - Cannot click between windows or click on UI elements with Mad Catz R.A.T. 3 mouse

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, keyboard, mouse, gnome-shell

I recently switched to Linux. Everything went fine, but when I installed the **gnome-shell**, it started to ignore clicks outside the focused window. I cannot click on another window to focus it or click on any gnome UI elements. The super key also does nothing. I installed **gnome-tweaks** and I use a user theme, but that shouldn't be the problem because the problem remained even when I had a fresh install. Also, sometimes when I reboot it works normally. But after another reboot, it comes back.

*PS- I found a very temporary fix: If I move the focused (or sometimes other windows) it will start recognizing my keystrokes. On Firefox I need to move the window by the bar with open tabs, as I cannot move it with the title bar.*

I read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971647/17-10-mouse-cant-click-on-gnome-elements-keyboard-misbehaving) by someone who had a very similar issue, but the solution did not work for me. I think it has to do something with **NVidia** drivers, because if I change them then the frequency of this happening changes.

Sorry if something is weirdly written. English is not my native language.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Linux! English shouldn't be a barrier in the way of solution as long as you can adequately explain your troubles. Cheerios! :)
PS - Windows key is supposedly refered to as the Super Key.

Comment: Thanks, I approved the edit. And changed the 'windows key' to super key.

Comment: Did you try *all* the answers posted to the [question you mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971647/17-10-mouse-cant-click-on-gnome-elements-keyboard-misbehaving)? For example are you in a Wayland session? What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: @pomsky The output of the command is x11. So I'm not in a Wayland session. I guess? EDIT 1 and 2: I'm dumb

Comment: Also, yes I did try all the answers. The second one even booted me to a black screen.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but don't have your mouse... I posted a more general question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143824/how-to-troubleshoot-gnome-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: My issue was also with my wireless mouse and once I saw this answer I just decided to unplug the USB dongle and plug it back in. This solved the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after doing some more research, I stumbled upon a [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068030/window-focus-gets-stuck-cannot-click-outside-of-window?rq=1) with the same question. It turned out to be a problem with my Mad Catz R.A.T. 3 mouse. I didn't realise that i didn't have any drivers for it. Here's how you can fix this issue.

Write this section to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"    Identifier "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct "Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

*PS: Here's a [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mad_Catz_Mouse) to ArchWiki. It has all the information you need to set up your mad catz mouse.*

Comment: Please do not delete your question!  Links to outside website may not work in the future, and you have attributed your answer to these outside sources *and* included the relevant bits to the answer that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my `Kingsis Peripherals Evoluent VerticalMouse 4`.  Appending the following to the bottom of `xorg.conf` file fixed it for me.  Thanks!

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier       "Mouse Remap"
    MatchDevicePath  "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchProduct     "Kingsis Peripherals Evoluent VerticalMouse 4"
    Option           "ButtonMapping"   "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I contracted the same issue on ubuntu 20.04 a few days after I started using a new mouse (Razer DeathAdder Elite). Perhaps it's related to the mouse. Or perhaps it's related to an system update that maybe didn't work out well today.

I was afraid I'd have to reinstall ubuntu, since it was mostly unusable, but [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1714105&page=2&s=4161c345adc443c594ceae0662b04086) suggested reinstalling compiz.
Compiz is a [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager), of which there are a few.

You can find out what your window manager is:
[How to determine which window manager is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running)

For me it turned out to be gnome-shell. Reinstalling it + restart did the trick, now everything is usable again. The Gnome-UI looks a bit different, so I don't know if perhaps the update was the issue (or just reinstalling deleted my previous config).
I'll see if it holds up, since I'm still using the new mouse.

I'm also thinking about starting a file-backup in case I do have to do a re-install some day...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thanks for posting an answer. Can you specify how did you reinstalled Gnome Shell? This would help others with the same issue. Also, I recommend including some information from the link you posted in case it becomes 404. You can find more information on how to write a good answer [in the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help).