# How to troubleshoot Gnome on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell

Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 18.04 has started to randomly become unresponsive some weeks ago. It was not a big deal at that time be cause it rarely happened. Since then it went worse and now this happens only a few seconds after I restart the shell with `killall -3 gnome-shell` or `Alt+F2` then `R` when this is working.

By unresponsive I mean that I cannot focus a window with the mouse (but Alt+Tab is working), the Super key has no effect, the left side dock cannot be clicked anymore, Alt+F2 is often not working. This is becoming a nightmare.

I disabled all my extensions but that didn't change anything. I looked in `/var/logs` but didn't find anything useful. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115001/gnome-cannot-click-between-windows-or-click-on-ui-elements-with-mad-catz-r-a-t) is describing my exact problem but I don't have the mouse is question.

So what is the best course of action to troubleshoot this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Once the Gnome Shell has "fully" crashed, i.e. I get back to the session login panel and all applications are lost, I get some time without problem. Then the issue pops up again.

I noticed that before (or after, I don't know?) each crash, there is this line in `/var/log/syslog`:

`gnome-shell[20080]: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed`

I couldn't find any pattern examining `/var/log/syslog` and nothing helpful on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few paths you might want to take:

### 1) **Create a new user.**

Making a new user as a troubleshooting step will rule out if your problems stem from your user's configuration files.  A new user will have all default configuration files.  Creating a new user also will not affect any of the files in your current user's home directory.

Add the new user and give them a home directory:

```
sudo useradd -m newusername
```

Give the new user sudo privileges (if you need them):

```
sudo adduser newusername sudo
```

Reboot and log into the new user you've just created.

If everything works, there must be problems in the configs under the home directory of your old user.  See #2 below for troubleshooting if you want to "rescue" this user.

You will likely want to delete a user, either the old or the new.  To do this, use the command...

```
sudo userdel -r username
```

... to permanently delete a user and its home folder.  This command cannot be run from the user to be deleted.

### 2) Manually delete configs

**You may want to inspect and delete configuration files** for software related to the problems you are having.  You can find user-specific configs in the hidden dotfiles & folders under the user's home directory beginning with: `/home/user/.` (mind the dot `.` after `user/`)

For example, you may want to force your GTK configuration files to generate new defaults by moving them to a backup location:

`sudo mv -r /home/user/.config/gtk-3.0 /home/user/.config/gtk-3.0-old/`

This would give you precise control over what aspects of the desktop you are tinkering with, but you could really spend all day doing this.

---

### 3) Reinstall GNOME

If your problems are not solved by wiping your configuration files, **a more thorough solution would be to completely reinstall GNOME**.

**You can do this two ways:**

---

### by using `apt-get install --reinstall`

Log into a virtual terminal with `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F3`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
sudo reboot
```

---

### purge & (re)install with `apt`

Log into a virtual terminal with `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F3`

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell
sudo reboot
```

`apt purge` will also remove system-level configuration files, however it will not remove configuration files in your home folder.

---

Comment: thank you but for some reason my problem has disappeared after a full gnome shell crash...

Comment: ...and came back :-( I edited my question.